# Visual Studio not debugging

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2005

I have a problem that has lately being bugging me on 2 different computers

What is happening is that I press F5, to compile my website, the website loads, but I cannot debug! Its like I am not running the website from visual studio at all. And then sometimes I restart my PC, and it comes back to normal. I have no idea what is the problem, and I have looked up this issue for quite a while now, but to no avail...

Can somebody shed some light on this? I have no clue what is happening here

Thanks

Comment: are you compiling for debug or for release?

Answer (score 1):

You could always try: Debug --> Attach to Process.

It tends to be either the aspnet_wp.exe (IIS 6.0, XP) or one of the W3WP.exe processes (IIS 6.0, Server 2003).

Comment: The problem is, that if i go to debug > attach to process > find aspnet_wp.exe, it is not there!

Is this the problem then?

Comment: I attached it to asghost.exe and it works!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

I have had this problem for months, thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Ok, false alarm :s it looks like it is able to debug.. but when I put a breakpoint, it doesnt :s

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: asghost.exe is a process belonging to Cognizance Identity and Access Management. I doubt this woudl be the right process to attach your debugger to. Do you have IIs configured to run your site? What is your setup like?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IE8 or running on Vista then you need to run Visual Studio 2005 with elevated privileges to get debugging to work nicely.

I found with IE8 due to the threading that I either had to close all the IE windows or run as admin. There was another hack which I can't remember and I think was fixed in VS2008 SP1 because I don't have that problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with how you are opening your project in VS. Make sure you selecting the correct project/solution file.

I was having a similar issue when opening a MVC project with Open->Website rather than with the .sln file (solution) saved in the root of the site.